# List elements wont add to a new list (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to split my list up between odd numbers and even numbers. So far my code is:

```
odds = []
evens = []
new_list = [1, 4, 2, 6, 5, 3, 7]
for index in new_list:
     if index % 2 == 0:
        evens += [index]
    else:
        odds += [index]
```

However, when I print the evens list it results in None. I have printed the numbers individually, as in:

```
 for index in new_list:
     if index % 2 == 0:
         evens += [index]
         print(index)
```

and the even numbers print. Why wont they add to the evens list ?

The odd numbers add to the list with no problems.

Edit:

The full function is:

```
def evens_at_end(list1):
    odds = []
    evens = []
    list2 = [3,4,5,9]
    for index in list1:
        if index % 2 == 0:
            evens += [index]
        else:
            odds += [index]

    new_list = list2 + evens

 return new_list
```

with list1 being [1, 4, 2, 6, 5, 3, 7]

Comment: Works fine for me except your `else` line is incorrectly indented.

Comment: oh, I didn't notice. thanks for telling me :)

Comment: How are you printing the list? If I just add `print evens` after your code it works. Are you putting that code in a function and perhaps forgetting to return `evens`?

Comment: i'm adding the evens list to another list, but it wont do so because is a NoneType. Basically: `list3 + evens` gives the error : TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list"

Comment: Show us ALL of the relevant code.

Comment: Maybe `list3` is `None`

Comment: Please fix your indention.  Where does `list2` come from?

Comment: Indentation is still incorrect. The `for` and `if` are on the same level, that would raise and exception.

Comment: It's still not all the relevant code. Don't say "with list1 being [1, 4, 2, 6, 5, 3, 7]", show the function being called with that list. And show where `list2` is defined. And then there's the broken indentation. Edit your question such that you can copy the code from the question into a new file and run it immediately.

Comment: What is `list 2 = [3,4,5,9]` supposed to do? There is an extra space.

Comment: Still not the right indentation! I'll say it again: Edit your question such that you can copy the code from the question into a new file and run it immediately.

Comment: updated it. list two is in the function, I just forgot to type it in the question.

Comment: Stop typing things manually. Copy paste.

Comment: when I copy and paste it puts all the text at the same length of the line. I tried that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list comprehensions

```
evens = [x for x in list1 if x % 2 == 0]
odds = [x for x in list1 if x not in evens]
```